# Enable a Storybook control conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, storybook

I use controls in a story to see different states of a component.
Some props only make sense if some other prop is enabled.

For example, I have 3 props:

- isEmployee - boolean
- isActive - boolean
- canContactInTheWeekend - boolean

Here, `canContactInTheWeekend` applies only if `isActive` is `true`.
To make it more clear for a developer, I'd like to disable `canContactInTheWeekend` toggle when `isActive` is `false`.

How can I achieve it with standard Storybook setup or via some plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are already using the `addon-knobs` https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-knobs.

You should be able to achieve what you want like this :

```
export const Default = () => {
    const isActive = boolean('isActive ', false);
    const canContactInTheWeekend = isActive ?  boolean('canContactInTheWeekend ', false) : false;

return (<.../>)
}
```

More exhaustive example : https://stephencharlesweiss.com/conditional-storybook-knobs/

Comment: Knobs have been replaced with [Controls](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-controls). I believe OP is using Controls.

Comment: @jorisw That question were asked some months before they formally deprecated knobs. I invite you to add an example with Controls because I didn't have chance to try them yet.

Comment: I would like to, unfortunately Controls don’t support it, and hence are a bit of a regression when compared to Knobs.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Conditional Controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#conditional-controls)

```js
argTypes: {
  canContactInTheWeekend: { control: 'boolean', if: { arg: 'isActive' } },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue was exactly the motivation for Flare, a principled alternative to Storybook Knobs and Storybook Controls. Here is how I would implement your example using Flare:

```js
pipe(
  of((isEmployee: boolean) => (otherProps: { isActive: boolean, canContactInTheWeekend: boolean }) => (<Contact {...{ isEmployee, ...otherProps }} />)),
  ap(checkbox({ label: "Employee", initial: false })),
  ap(
    pipe(
      switch_({ label: "Active", initial: false }),
      chain(ifElse(
        pipe(
          checkbox({ label: "Weekend OK", initial: false }),
          map(canContactInTheWeekend => ({ isActive: true, canContactInTheWeekend }))
        ),
        of({ isActive: false, canContactInTheWeekend: false })
      ))
    )
  )
)
```

Here's a complete working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-paper-ulqrg?file=/src/main.tsx:719-1276

For more info about Flare, check out https://flare.js.org/

Note that I'm the author.